# Unity sprite packer is disabled

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, texturepacker

I am trying to open the sprite packer in unity, and when I go to **window -> sprite packer** it is disable.
I tryed to go to ** Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor** as was suggested in http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html
but it didn't work.

I am using unity 4.5.2f1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sprite Packer is a [Pro Only feature](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-free-and-sprite-packing.211028/):

Sprite Packer is a Pro Only feature. Free users can still use atlases created using 3rd party software.
Currently there are no plans to enable this in Unity Free.